# How to deallocate llvm::module

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a small language parser that uses LLVM to generate and run code, based on the Kaleidoscope tutorial.

My constraint is that I have to recreate the module because I need to process the same input file multiple times, and after the first compilation, LLVM would complain about the module already containing functions, x, etc. The only way forward I see is to recreate the module in between, and this means that I have to recreate `ExecutionEngine` as well.

However, there are a huge amount of memory leaks occurring which I want to get rid of. How do I properly deallocate the `llvm::Module` and `llvm::ExecutionEngine` ?

If I simply delete both, it segfaults somewhere in LLVM. My current implementation goes like this:

```
TheExecutionEngine->removeModule(module);
delete module();
delete TheExecutionEngine;
```

However, there are still about 14000 leaks reported, so this seems wrong.

I do not need to duplicate any existing functions in a module. I just want a fresh, empty one.

Comment: Did you take a look at CloneModule? Might help in the first place to duplicate the module - http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/CloneModule_8cpp_source.html#l00034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create `ExecutionEngine` and `Module` instances multiple times during the lifetime of your program, and clean them up properly.

Do not delete the Module separately, since `ExecutionEngine` "owns" it once you `addModule`. This means it will take care of deleting and cleaning up.

In LLVM it's always best to learn from examples. I suggest you take a look at the source code of `tools/lli/lli.cpp`, which does all of what you need, including cleanup.