# LLVM API: correct way to create/dispose

Tags: llvm, dispose

I'm attempting to implement a simple JIT compiler using the LLVM C API. So far, I have no problems generating IR code and executing it, that is: until I start disposing objects and recreating them.

What I basically would like to do is to clean up the JIT'ted resources the moment they're no longer used by the engine. What I'm basically attempting to do is something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    // Initialize module & builder
    InitializeCore(GetGlobalPassRegistry());
    module = ModuleCreateWithName(some_unique_name);
    builder = CreateBuilder();

    // Initialize target & execution engine
    InitializeNativeTarget();
    engine = CreateExecutionEngineForModule(...);
    passmgr = CreateFunctionPassManagerForModule(module);
    AddTargetData(GetExecutionEngineTargetData(engine), passmgr);
    InitializeFunctionPassManager(passmgr);

    // [... my fancy JIT code ...] --** Will give a serious error the second iteration

    // Destroy
    DisposePassManager(passmgr);
    DisposeExecutionEngine(engine);
    DisposeBuilder(builder);
    // DisposeModule(module); //--> Commented out: Deleted by execution engine

    Shutdown();
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working correctly: the second iteration of the loop I get a pretty bad error...

So to summarize: what's the correct way to destroy and re-create the LLVM API?

Comment: I suppose, you should delete module first.

Comment: @arrowdodger It appears to me that that is impossible. The execution engine references the module and does a 'delete'. Even though every fibre in my body urges to delete it as well, your program will surely segfault if you do.

Comment: Try moving `InitializeNativeTarget()` out of loop, then.

Comment: No, that didn't help... this isn't supposed to be a trial and error process. I want to _know_ that things are away after the loop; this is a long running process that compiles massive amounts of code, so I don't want memory leaks.

Comment: I had a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891889/how-to-deallocate-llvmmodule)... But apparently nobody knows how to deallocate LLVM properly

Comment: @antipattern Hmm, 6 months old. Thanks for that. Just wondering: does the answer that you marked correct solve the resource leaks (I only care about per-compile leakage; initialization code that's leaking is fine)? Or did you end up hacking RAII into LLVM by yourself?

Comment: Neither, it is still work in progress to find a solution. Priorities :(

Comment: On a second thought, do you really need a full-blown destruction&reinitialization of LLVM? For me, it works if I simply delete the execution engine and then recreate the module and execution engine. After having another look at it now, the resulting Leaks seem to be mostly one-time initialization leaks. Not all of them, but the remainder might very well be resulting from other mistakes in my usage of LLVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as Answer because the code's too long. If possible and no other constraints, try to use LLVM like this. I am pretty sure the `Shutdown()` inside the loop is the culprit here. And I dont think it would hurt to keep the `Builder` outside, too. This reflects well the way I use LLVM in my JIT.

```
InitializeCore(GetGlobalPassRegistry());
InitializeNativeTarget();
builder = CreateBuilder();

while (true)
{
    // Initialize module & builder

    module = ModuleCreateWithName(some_unique_name);


    // Initialize target & execution engine
    engine = CreateExecutionEngineForModule(...);
    passmgr = CreateFunctionPassManagerForModule(module);
    AddTargetData(GetExecutionEngineTargetData(engine), passmgr);
    InitializeFunctionPassManager(passmgr);

    // [... my fancy JIT code ...] --** Will give a serious error the second iteration

    // Destroy
    DisposePassManager(passmgr);
    DisposeExecutionEngine(engine);             
}
DisposeBuilder(builder);
Shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give this a go; let's see what happens. I do notice that you don't destroy the module; was that on purpose?

Comment: I've profiled quite a bit and it seems the leaks are all gone. A few important pointers: Always dispose the execution engine, otherwise you get a major memory leak. ALso, be sure to dispose all generic values you pass to LLVM functions (including the function return value). In combination with your solution, that did the trick for me. Thanks again, I'll mark your answer as the correct solution.

Comment: Yep, as I have found out the painful (segfault) way, the module is owned by the Execution Engine and gets deleted with it.

Comment: [OT] as a fellow user, I'm wondering what your experiences so far are with LLVM; I'm compiling code using LLVM from .NET as one of the targets... and so far I find it relatively slow (even compared to .NET IL) and a very painful process. I basically only care about raw performance for my applications. But perhaps my expectations are much too high; would you care to share yours?

Comment: We don't use LLVM with Clang as most folks do...Instead we built a JIT compiler for a small scripting language which calls into prebuilt c++ functions compiled with Visual Studio. Therefore the compilation times are out of comparison and the performance is not a big factor because the main workload is inside these precompiled functions.
However, from what I've read about it, LLVM is on par with other compilers in terms of benchmark performance..
I like how quickly one can use it to build a custom JIT - I would not know of any alternatives here. The only drawback is the lack of documentation...

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* program init */
LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();
LLVMLinkInMCJIT();





    ctx->context = LLVMContextCreate();
    ctx->builder = LLVMCreateBuilderInContext(ctx->context);
    LLVMParseBitcodeInContext2(ctx->context, module_template_buf, &module) // create module

    do IR code creation
    {
        function = LLVMAddFunction(ctx->module, "my_func")
        LLVMAppendBasicBlockInContext(ctx->context, ...
        LLVMBuild...
        ...
    }
    optional optimization
    {
        LLVMPassManagerBuilderRef pass_builder = LLVMPassManagerBuilderCreate();
        LLVMPassManagerBuilderSetOptLevel(pass_builder, 3);
        LLVMPassManagerBuilderSetSizeLevel(pass_builder, 0);
        LLVMPassManagerBuilderUseInlinerWithThreshold(pass_builder, 1000);
        LLVMPassManagerRef function_passes = LLVMCreateFunctionPassManagerForModule(ctx->module);
        LLVMPassManagerRef module_passes = LLVMCreatePassManager();
        LLVMPassManagerBuilderPopulateFunctionPassManager(pass_builder, function_passes);
        LLVMPassManagerBuilderPopulateModulePassManager(pass_builder, module_passes);
        LLVMPassManagerBuilderDispose(pass_builder);
        LLVMInitializeFunctionPassManager(function_passes);
        for (LLVMValueRef value = LLVMGetFirstFunction(ctx->module); value;
             value = LLVMGetNextFunction(value))
        {
            LLVMRunFunctionPassManager(function_passes, value);
        }
        LLVMFinalizeFunctionPassManager(function_passes);
        LLVMRunPassManager(module_passes, ctx->module);
        LLVMDisposePassManager(function_passes);
        LLVMDisposePassManager(module_passes);
    }

    optional for debug
    {
        LLVMVerifyModule(ctx->module, LLVMAbortProcessAction, &error);
        LLVMPrintModule
    }
    if (LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule(&ctx->engine, ctx->module, 0, &error) != 0)
    my_func = (exec_func_t)(uintptr_t)LLVMGetFunctionAddress(ctx->engine, "my_func");

    LLVMRemoveModule(ctx->engine, ctx->module, &ctx->module, &error);
    LLVMDisposeModule(ctx->module);
    LLVMDisposeBuilder(ctx->builder);

    do
    {
         my_func(...);
    }

    LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine(ctx->engine);
    LLVMContextDispose(ctx->context);



/* program finit */
LLVMShutdown();
```